# Create dynamic names for ng-model in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

**Problem -**

`ng-model` are not creating dynamically. My input boxes are creating dynamically and I am trying to create `ng-model` dynamic like `test[1]`, `test[2]` etc but when I firebug the form I am getting only - `test[shiftnumber]` for all input elements.

**HTML code** -

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select id="shiftnumbers"
            ng-model="event.shiftnumber"
            ng-change="addShiftNumber(event.shiftnumber)"
            ng-options="timeslot.value as timeslot.name for timeslot in shiftnumbers"
            ng-init="event.shiftnumber = shiftnumbers[0].value"
            class="btn">
    </select>
    <div ng-repeat="shiftnumber in selectedShiftnumbers">
      <input type="text" name="test{{shiftnumber}}" ng-model="test[shiftnumber]" /> {{shiftnumber + 1}}
    </div>
</body>
```

**SCRIPT Code -**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){

    $scope.shiftnumbers = [];
    for(var i=0; i< 23; i++) {
        $scope.shiftnumbers.push({name: i, value: i});
    }

    $scope.addShiftNumber = function(num){
      $scope.selectedShiftnumbers = [];
      for(var i=0; i< num; i++) {
        $scope.selectedShiftnumbers.push(i);
      }
    }
});
```

PLNKR  - http://plnkr.co/edit/PL9sVAKn5UsZECPsOvnk?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't have defined `$scope.test[0]`, `$scope.test[1]` (you're using `ng-model="test[shiftnumber]"`, so there should be `$scope.test[shiftnumber]`).

Try

```
$scope.addShiftNumber = function(num){
  $scope.test = [];
  $scope.selectedShiftnumbers = [];
  for(var i=0; i< num; i++) {
    $scope.selectedShiftnumbers.push(i);
    $scope.test.push('');
  }
}
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YO676mTxcMQYWjUATRMP?p=preview)